# How to make a swimming goggle fog free?

Tags: swimming

Do I have to buy new one every 2-3 months to swim fog free? Is there a way to protect the anti-fog feature for long times?

Answer (score 13):

There are a few low tech methods:

Toothpaste (Smear a bit then rinse free, be cautious as some people are sensitive to toothpaste around the eyes)

Saliva

Anti Fog spray

I've had good results with the aquasphere line, but eventually all glasses fog over. I usually just spit on the insides, smear around, then rinse them out and slap them back on. During practice, I generally just smear pool water over the inside with my thumbs. After a while, fogginess just doesn't bother you any more.

Answer (score 5):

"Fogging" on the inside of the googles is caused by temperature differences between the inside and outside of the lens. This is the same reason your car window fogs up when you turn on the heat in the winter.

**The simplest solution is to dunk your googles in the pool before you put them on.** I've done this for over 8 years as a swimmer and I've never had issues with fog, no matter how old the goggles were.

I used to rub them when I was a kid but then my coach showed me the dunking technique and it changed my life forever... :)

Comment: Master, it is the same thing I am following but my goggles are fogging within just 300 to 400 m swim. Should I go for a costlier goggles? Or is it the same case for all goggles?

Comment: I do both,  rub saliva really well & then dunk them.  Been doing this for years on my swedish goggles. Always work.

Comment: @Freakyuser, it's both the same case and not for all goggles. Here's why: the antifog coating is practically the same for all of them, but the shape and fit of the goggles also affect fogging in different ways. I have a basket full of goggles at home through the years, but the only ones I use most are the cheapest, most basic swedish goggles. They cost anywhere between USD $2.50 to $8 and work wonder for me. The coating is gone after about two weeks, but I rub saliva and dunk and they work just as well for at least a year each pair until I either lose them or scratch them up too much.

Comment: What brand do you use, because I've dunked my Hollis diving mask, Aquasphere goggles, Aegend (Chinese rando brand) goggles, and they all fog repeatedly. Saliva didn't help much.

Answer (score 4):

My experience: put your goggles into the water, salivate by your tongue and put immediately on.

EDIT: I'd never use any anti-fog chemicals now. Why? When the protection is partially off and goggles start slowly fogging you will be forced to think about licking chemicals in case you would like to use my tip. So don't use any chemicals, just salivate it. I'd like to have something chemicals free on my eyes :)

Comment: I was taught this by my coach in school when we did swimming. Its was gross at first, but it works.

Answer (score 3):

A cheap and fast solution is using saliva.

I use quite frequently in all my glasses (swimming and spearfishing) since ever. It is quite effective.

Water the lens. Spit on the inside and rub it. Wash it.

For spearfishing there are also some film one might use on the lenses (they solved the fog problem in one of my masks) :

[image]

A more expensive solution, that I know of, is athletes that in every competition wear a new set of goggles.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good list of potential solutions. Even though it is for a scuba mask, it pertains to any goggles as well. (ex: burn glass with lighter, toothpaste, saliva, baby shampoo, glycerin soap). http://scuba-diving-explained.com/no-more-fog-in-my-scuba-mask-secrets-to-a-clear-mask

Answer (score 0):

While taking the initial shower, I put liquid soap in them and some water, and live them for 1 min. Then I wash them thoroughly with water, and try not to touch the interior with my fingers. Be careful if you are sensitive to liquid soap, then rinse them good.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of buying anti-fog goggles (which no swim goggle is truly anti-fog--they all say so, but it's one of the biggest jokes amongst swimmers), make sure you are buying swim goggles that are:

- Light for indoor use. Dark tinted goggles look cool, but aren't super
  functional for poorly lit pools. Especially when the anti-fog
  eventually wears off.
- Dark tinted for outdoor use. Seems obvious, but
  you'd be surprised how often swimmers show up to outdoor lap swim
  with clear-lens goggles. They end up squinting through their swim,
  unable to swim backstroke without closing their eyes (and swimming
  into the lane rope and other swimmers as a result).

The best thing you can do is to keep your fingers out from the inside of the lenses--wiping sweat, water, whatever--will peel away the film of anti-fog.